# Halmos, Frechet-Neumann theorem, and polarization in vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Look at Halmos' book on vector spaces (1987); Ch. III, page 123,
exercise 2.

*If $x$ and $y$ are vectors in a unitary space then the scalar
product is given by the formula*
$$
4(x,y)=\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|x+iy\|^2-i\|x-iy\|^2.
$$
What confuses me here is the absent of a parallelogram identity. But
the Frechet-Neumann theorem, with the same statement, exploits this
very `parallelogram'.

To put this differently,

1. One has a vector space with some (Hermitian) inner product
   $(x,y)$.
2. One has a norm $\|x\|$ on the space.
3. Should we imply a correspondence, say $(x,x)=\|x\|^2$, between
   axioms of $(x,y)$ and $\|x\|$? If not, what would change in this
   case?

Then, again, the question above: statement in the exercise and the
parallelogram identity -- where it is hiding? -- by Frechet-Neumann? Do
I overlook something? Incidentally, Halmos' definition of $(x,y)$,
and of unitary space (p. 121) does not touch upon the structure of a
norm.

Comment: It is very hard to get what your problem is. You know that every scalar product induces a norm via $ \Vert \cdot  \Vert := \sqrt{\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}$ and this is the norm one considers here?

Comment: Yes, it induces a norm. But what about the parallelogram identity for it?